# android usbRequest in new versions not as 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, arduino, usb-drive

first of all i would like to say thanks 
with out guys like you out there , it would be difficult for us to understand such things 
....

I used UsbRequest and Requestwiat to read fixed packet size data of 5 bytes ,, it works perfectly for me (4.1.2) but unfortunately it doesn't on (4.3 and also 4.4).
Through my searching I found that changed done to newer version >>2.2 , http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28023

is that related to my problem ?
It's my graduation project and I'm not that professional programmer so any notice ,idea or suggestion  would help me to start searching .

Abdulaziz

Regards

public class UsbSerialService extends Service   {

```
static LinkedBlockingQueue<Double> serialQueueForUI = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Double>();


public static  UsbManager mUsbManager;
public  static UsbDevice mUsbDevice;
private volatile UsbDeviceConnection mUsbConnection = null;
private volatile UsbEndpoint mInUsbEndpoint = null;
int bufferMaxLength=5;

public static Handler UIHandler;


private UsbRunnable mLoop;
private Thread mUsbThread;



@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}
public void onCreate(){

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     if (!initDevice()) {
         stopSelf();
         return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
     }      
     mLoop = new UsbRunnable();
    mUsbThread = new Thread(mLoop);
    mUsbThread.start();       

    return START_STICKY;


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mUsbDevice = null;
    if (mUsbConnection != null) {
        mUsbConnection.close();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


private class UsbRunnable implements Runnable{

    public void run() {

        {   
            ByteBuffer inBuffer =  ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferMaxLength);
         while(mUsbDevice != null ) 
              {
             UsbRequest inRequest = new UsbRequest(); 
             inRequest.initialize(mUsbConnection, mInUsbEndpoint);
             if(inRequest.queue(inBuffer, bufferMaxLength) == true)
                 {
                 mUsbConnection.requestWait(); 
                 // wait for this request to be completed
                 // at this point buffer contains the data received
                 UsbSerialService.updateReceivedData(inBuffer.array());
                 inBuffer.clear();
                   }                   
               }
         } }}





public static void updateReceivedData(final byte[] Data)  {


                List<Character> doubleBuilder = new ArrayList<Character>();
                Double d =null;
                char c;
                   for(int i=0;i<Data.length;i++)
                    {c = (char)Data[i];
                    doubleBuilder.add(c);}

                    char charArray[] = new char[doubleBuilder.size()];
                     for (int j=0; j < charArray.length; j++) 
                     charArray[j] = doubleBuilder.get(j);
                     String stringVal = String.copyValueOf(charArray);

                     try {d = Double.valueOf(stringVal);
                    serialQueueForUI.offer(d);
                     }
                     catch (NumberFormatException e){}



                     doubleBuilder.clear();


                } 










 private boolean initDevice() {
        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mUsbConnection = mUsbManager.openDevice(mUsbDevice);
        if (!mUsbConnection.claimInterface(mUsbDevice.getInterface(1), true))
        {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "opening_device_failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;

        }
        if (mUsbConnection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "opening_device_failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
        UsbInterface usbInterface = mUsbDevice.getInterface(1);
        if (!mUsbConnection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "claimning_interface_failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mUsbConnection.close();
            return false;
        }
        // USB serial converter setup
        // Set control line state
        mUsbConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x22, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
        // Set line encoding.
        setBaudrate(115200);

        for (int i = 0; i < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
            if (usbInterface.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                if (usbInterface.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                    mInUsbEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(i);
                } 
            }
        }

        if (mInUsbEndpoint == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no_in_endpoint_found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mUsbConnection.close();
            return false;
        }



        return true;
    }

 public void setBaudrate(int baudrate) {
        byte[] baudByte = new byte[4];

        baudByte[0] = (byte) (baudrate & 0x000000FF);
        baudByte[1] = (byte) ((baudrate & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        baudByte[2] = (byte) ((baudrate & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        baudByte[3] = (byte) ((baudrate & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
         mUsbConnection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x20, 0, 0, new byte[] {
                baudByte[0], baudByte[1], baudByte[2], baudByte[3], 0x00, 0x00,
                0x08}, 7, 15);

    }
 static void show(Context context, UsbDevice device) {
     mUsbDevice = device;
             final  Intent intent = new Intent(context, UsbSerialService.class);
             context.startService(intent);

         }


}
```